# IHTMLDocument -- Click an IHTMLElement by ID, not Name

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, mshtml

The input field that I need to fill in has it's name value set to j_password.  The button I would like to click is a link within a div that has an id set to loginBtn.

I'm trying something like this:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)webBrowserControl.Document);
((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item("j_password")).setAttribute("value", password);
((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item("loginBtn")).click();
```

But the button is never clicked.  I can't tell if it is because it isn't really a button, or if it is because it doesn't have a name attribute and I'm trying to use an id.

Anyway, does anyone see a fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the click call did not throw a NullReferenceException, then you found the element. But it is better to use the standard IHTMLDocument3::getElementById orIHTMLDocument3::getElementsByName instead of document.all for the future.

As for why click does not work, it depends on how click is supposed to work. There are a lot of side effects of a mouse click, and the browser may limit those effects if the mouse is not over the element between a mouse down and a mouse up.

If the click is supposed to call a javascript function, just call the function directly (ExecScript). Otherwise, find the login form element, call its onsubmit handler function if there is one, then call its submit method.

Comment: Under further analysis it's clear that the link I would need to click doesn't have an id or name.  It executes javascript on its onClick event.  Do you know of a good way to replicate that?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 I am having a similar scenario in which the click is having side effects. What if I don't know the handler function also?Is there a way to find it in .net? Will putting the mouse pointer above the div element work?

Comment: you can call IHTMLElement3.FireEvent to trigger the event handler. Note this does not really move the mouse.